# Regex replace url encoded string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in which I want to replace the text `[[signature]]` with a given value, but because it is encoded, the text looks like `%5B%5Bsignature%5D%5D`.

How do I replace this using a regular expression? This snippet works, but only if the string is not encoded:

```
$replace = preg_replace('/\[\[signature\]\]/', 'replaced!', $html);
```

Comment: Why then use  a regex? Use [`str_replace('%5B%5Bsignature%5D%5D', 'replaced!', $html)`](https://ideone.com/Jsb31o)

Comment: Use the [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method available in Php before using your regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have encoded the string, so just decode it then run your replace.

```
$html = urldecode($html);
$replace = preg_replace('/\[\[signature\]\]/', 'replaced!', $html);
```

You can always encode it again afterwards if you need:

```
$html = urlencode($html);
```

---

**Non-Regex Solution**

If your find/replace is really that simple then you don't even need to use regex. Just do a standard string replace:

```
$html = str_replace('[[signature]]', 'replaced!', $html);
```